# How to make a discord bot reply what you have said?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm new at coding and I want to  make a bot that says whatever you say after the `!say` command. For example - `!say hello`, bot replies with "hello".

What I tried:

```js
let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

if(message.content.startsWith(PREFIX + 'say')) {
    var say = args[1].join(" ");
    message.channel.send(say)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`args` is an array of strings, so `args[1]` is a string and therefore has no function `join`.

Try this:

```js
const args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ')

if (message.content.startsWith(PREFIX + 'say')) {
    const say = args[1]
    message.channel.send(say)
}
```

You might want to take a look at the [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide) (which has [a section on handling command arguments](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html)).

Comment: @JonasPetrėtis You're welcome - please mark this answer as accepted by clicking the green tick. That's how this question gets marked as answered and other people can easily find the answer. :)

Comment: But getting only args[1] it`s not right way, if message has more then 1 world this will repeat only first world...

Comment: @Cipher Yea, what should I do then? that it would reply all words after !say?

Comment: As variant splice args. `let say = args.splice(1, args.length -1).join(' ')`
but need some check before,  like, `if(args.length < 2) return`